# Angular not bootstraping on page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Some times when I reload the web page by the browser reload button or changing the page url, Angular not load the module app.

I'm using angular **1.3.5** and they are my module dependencies and routers:

**app.js** :

```
var app = angular.module('aip.app', [
  'ngAnimate',    // Angular animation module.
  'ui.bootstrap', // Angular bootstrap directives module.
  'ui.router',    // Angular UI Router module.
  'aip.auth',     // Authentication module.
  'aip.common',   // Common directives and services module.
  'aip.i18n',     // Translation module.
  'app.templates' // Application templates.
]);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

  /**
   * Routing application.
   */
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'src/app/components/auth/login/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController',
      data: {
        checkSession: true,
        redirectOnChangeSession: true
      }
    })
    .state('logout', {
      url: '/logout',
      templateUrl: 'src/app/components/auth/logout/logout.html',
      controller: 'LogoutController',
      data: {
        checkSession: false
      }
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'src/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.html',
      data: {
        checkSession: true,
        redirectOnChangeSession: true
      }
    });

  // Use pretty urls
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
});
```

**index.html** :

```
  <html lang="en" ng-app="aip.app">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title ng-bind-template="{{$state.current.title || 'AIP'}}"></title>

    <!-- App style -->
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/img/favicon.ico" rel="shotcut icon">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">        </script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
        <div ui-view class="page-view" ng-cloak ng-hide="loading"></div>
        <div class="loader text-center" ng-show="loading">
          <div class="spinner">
            <div class="cube1"></div>
            <div class="cube2"></div>
          </div>
          <h3 ng-cloak style="display: none" ng-style="displayMessage">{{ bootstrapMessage }}</h3>
        </div>
        <script src="/js/vendor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/js/app.templates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**server.js** :

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/public' });
});
```

Any solution?

Comment: When html5mode is true, and you refresh your browser, the request first lands on server instead of Angular intercepting it. To make html5mode work you also need to do url rewrite on the server, such that the correct html is returned (mostly it is index page html).

Comment: Would help to see the code for bootstrapping your module and including your scripts.

Comment: If that is your server code, is that a catch all route after the other routes are defined? Otherwise, how would your `/js/*.js` URLs resolve?

Comment: I use `app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));` **before** `app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/public' });
});`

Comment: Same with `/img` I assume?

Answer (score 0):

May be the html page is unable to find app.js...Try to replace

```
<script src="/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

with this  


 <script src="./js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is that Angular aren't sending the request to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that works when the url are without another port like *:3000 (that I've been using previously) but with the port 80 works perfectly.